# Saving format from overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I often faced that, my presentation document on TexMake show n warning and also, no output

when I try to copy all the document script to overleaf, I get a very excellent compiling process (I get my output), now I want to ask how to save the output from overleaf in a presentation format that can be presented by any Latex editor such as in my case TexMaker?
I do not like to get in pdf (I hope to have active presentation)

Comment: This is really an Overleaf question, but if you click on the Menu icon at the top left, there are two large icons to download Source and PDF.  Download the Source to be able to edit it in TeXMaker.  But be aware that Overleaf hides lots of warnings and even errors so you may still have trouble compiling locally. Also make sure you have the same year of TeXLive installed locally as you are using to compile on Overleaf.

Answer (score 1):

Tom from Overleaf Support here.

While I can't know for sure why your project compiles in Overleaf, but does not compile locally, I agree with Alan's comment that the probable cause is that Overleaf uses nonstopmode. This means that the compilation does not stop at errors. So a PDF is produced, but it's most likely corrupted around the errors (or anywhere, for that sake).

You can check whether this is the case by adding a file called `latexmkrc` (without any file extension) into your project's top folder, with the following contents:

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --halt-on-error %O %S';
$lualatex = 'lualatex --halt-on-error %O %S';
$xelatex = 'xelatex --halt-on-error %O %S';
```

This will switch the Overleaf compiler from the "nonstop" mode to the "strict" mode, where LaTeX errors actually stop the compilation.